# how to get through of vba runtime error 3219 operation is not allowed in this context

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

This error appears when following code is run on Movies.accdb access database, but works fine on other databases.I got this database on wiseowl tutorial website.
here is my code:

```
Const cnstrAccess As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sam\Desktop\Today\Movies.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Sub ADOModifyingDataWIthRecordset()

Dim MoviesConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim MoviesData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim r As Range
Set MoviesConn = New ADODB.Connection

MoviesConn.ConnectionString = cnstrAccess
MoviesConn.Open

On Error GoTo CloseConnection

Set MoviesData = New ADODB.Recordset
With MoviesData
    .ActiveConnection = MoviesConn
    .Source = "tblFilm"
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open

On Error GoTo CloseRecordset
Sheet2.Activate
    For Each r In Sheet2.Range("A2", Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    .AddNew  
    .Fields("FilmName").Value = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
    .Fields("FilmReleaseDate").Value = r.Offset(0, 2).Value
    .Fields("FilmRunTimeMinutes").Value = 101
    .Update 'error is thrown on this line
    
    Next r
End With

CloseRecordset:
MoviesData.Close

CloseConnection:
MoviesConn.Close

Set MoviesData = Nothing
Set MoviesConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Double-check everything. There must be something different with this database compared with the others.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As you suggested i tried trimming my code ex it works when i update field values instead of addnew method. Here is shortened code.

Comment: ```Do until .EOF
If .fields("FilmRunTimeMinutes").value =200 then
.fields("FilmRunTimeMinutes").value=300

Comment: This code is in Excel to transfer data to Access? Why is Excel involved? Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.